# Normalizing the CodeMirror OnKeyEvent with jQuery

Tags: jquery, event-handling, jquery-events, codemirror

I'm using [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net) along with jQuery to provide syntax highlighting on a pet PoC project. It's been doing great, until I realized that CodeMirror seems to be capturing key press events on the DOM in such a way that it stops *global* application hotkeys from working when I'm currently typing into a CM-enabled textarea.

For simplicity's sake, let's assume that I have the following listener on my page:

```
var hotkey = function (e) {
    if (e.shiftKey) { alert('foo'); }
};
$(document).keypress(hotkey);
```

This would work everywhere in the page, except when I have a CM textarea in focus.

To try to get around this, I tried utilizing CM's onKeyEvent option, along with attempting to normalize the `event` object being passed by CM's handler with `jQuery.Event` like so:

```
var cm = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(someTextArea, {
    onKeyEvent : function (editor, event) {
        hotkey($.Event(event));
    }
});
```

This successfully gets the `keydown` and `keypress` events over on to my `hotkey` handler.

The problem is, the "normalized" `event` object doesn't seem to be normalized enough, as referencing something trivial as `e.shiftKey` in the `hotkey` scope returns `undefined`. (I do get `e.type` correctly as either `keydown` or `keypress` though, so I know I'm passing in an `event` object.)

**Is there anything I'm missing here that's causing my `event` to have missing properties, or am I just screwed?**

I could definitely just double back and access raw event properties, but, hey, I'd really love to be able to utilize jQuery-normalized objects as much as the next person almost anywhere I need to (and browser-agnosticism is just the start of it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.Event` is for creating custom events, i.e. to trigger them on your own later. You want `$.event.fix`.

```
var cm = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(someTextArea, {
    onKeyEvent : function (editor, e) {
        hotkey($.event.fix(e));
    }
});
```