# CodeMirror: Catching Enter Key prevents line breaks

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I used the extraKeys-option of CodeMirror 3.12 to detect when the user starts a new line:

```
extraKeys: {
    "Enter": onNewLine
}
```

onNewLine() does nothing but a console.log(). Now CodeMirror ignores that key. You can't start a new line anymore. Is there a way to hook up additional functionality on a new-line-event without interfering CodeMirror internals? I just want to analyze the text of the recently closed line.

Comment: Did you try other key events to make sure it is just this event that is not working? Checkout this post, maybe this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902683/normalizing-the-codemirror-onkeyevent-with-jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a line break at the end of onNewLine function.
This should work

```
 function onNewLine(e){
    console.log(e);
    editor.replaceSelection("\n" ,"end");
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I found that returning CodeMirror.Pass also works:

```
function onNewLine(e) {
    console.log("Enter key was pressed!");
    return CodeMirror.Pass;
}
```

From the documentation:

> A key handler function may return CodeMirror.Pass to indicate that it has decided not to handle the key, and other handlers (or the default behavior) should be given a turn.

This seems to work even if the handler does perform an action.  In my case I was using the editor.indentLine function to indent the current line when the user pressed the enter key.